# Find a File name, with not exacly all the name

Tags: python, windows, filenames

I have the following  issue.
I have other program ( Not python), that save the file with: the constant name + random number.

For example:
file1=("C:\Users\Soc  DRU  USD 002\Banco Interlocutor FB03_20230602015727981.png")

the name in this case :\Banco Interlocutor FB03_20230602015727981.png"
the constant is : Banco Interlocutor FB03_ and the random number is 20230602015727981
The next time that I will run the program the random number will change, and Python will not find the file.

Is there any way to say to Python: search the file that start with name "Banco Interlocutor FB03_"?

Is there any way to say to Python: search the file that start with name "Banco Interlocutor FB03_"?

Comment: You can make use of [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard python library [`os.listdir(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) to get `list` of files in your current directory

```py
# import os module
import os

# get files in current directory
files = os.listdir()
```

Then you can use `str.startswith(...)` method to check if filenames start with your prefix. I'm gonna use `filter` to create another list with filenames that start with required prefix:

```py
prefix = "Banco Interlocutor FB03_"

# creating filter iterator object
filter_object = filter(lambda v: v.startswith(prefix), files)

# creating list from filter iterator
featured_files = list(filter_object)

# displaying files that were selected
print(featured_files)
```